# Does a sequence defined by $u_{n+1} = \frac{a+u_n}{a-u_n}$ a special name?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's have

$$u_{n+1} = \frac{a+u_n}{a-u_n}$$

Does this type of sequence have a name, like arithmetic ones?

Is there literature about them?

Comment: "Literacy"? you mean "literature" I think?

Comment: Are the capital $U_{n+1}$ and lower-case $u_n$ supposed to be part of the same sequence?

Comment: Thanks both of you for pointing out these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recurrence, a non-linear one at that. It is also called an [iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function). Only for some very specific cases of $f$ in $u_{n + 1} = f(u_n)$ are closed solutions available (your example happens to be one).

Comment: On the other hand $a_{n+1}=\frac{a+a_n}{a-a_n}$ *always* has a closed form, depending on the eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix}1 & a \\ -1 & a\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank, now I know what to look for.